# How to get n followers with Linq To Twitter

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I am trying to get n followers where n could be 1,2,3,4 etc.. By default Linq To Twitter return all the followers. Is there any way I can define how many followers I need? My current code look like this

```
var followers = twitterCtx.Friendship
                   .Where(f => f.Type == FriendshipType.FollowersList
                       && f.UserID == twitterUserId.ToString())
                   .Select(f => new TwitterData()
                         {

                            Followers = f.Users.Where(t => t.Protected == false).Select(s => s).ToList()
                          ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Followers = f.Users.Where(t => !t.Protected).Take(n).ToList()
```

Comment: Wow, that's really fast and up to the mark. Thank you very much Sir

Comment: I will mark your comment as an answer within 10 mins. Can you please help me a little bit more. I am getting this  issue when I put my Twitter project inside Class Library and try to access with Win Form App. Any suggestion?

Comment: This issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m