# DLL stops executing after adding config block

Tags: c#

I have a DLL which require a little bit config block inside `App.config`.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.18.0" newVersion="4.2.18.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

If I put the above config block my DLL stops executing in the middle and releases all the resources which is weird. On the other hand, if I try to do the same with a console app, it properly executes. Any suggestion please?

Comment: How are you running your dll in first case?

Comment: I simply put the reference of my dll in winform app and add config block inside app.config and when I execute my form, It stop executing

Comment: Does your main app also reference System.Net.Http.Primitives?

Comment: No error, It just stop execute further. If I remove the config block getting error related to the assembly "Could Load file or assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives version 1.5.0.0....

Comment: Can you remove the reference from the main app or is it required? If required is it incompatible to the dll-needed version?

Comment: This might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m

Comment: @Uwe That's why I added the config block but it stops execution in the middle.

Comment: @Matt I already checked that post, that's why I added the config block. The error which is mentioned there, previously I was getting that one. But not stuck into this weird issue. Any idea?

Comment: I am trying to resolve this issue from last night. Please help me to fix out this issue

Comment: keep waiting for someone who can help me to get rid of this issue.