# PackageReference Redirect underlying package?

Tags: nuget, assembly-binding-redirect, packagereference

I'm using a NuGet package (IdentityModel.OidcClient 3.1.2) and this throws an error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The version in the bin folder is `Newtonsoft.Json.dll v11.0.2.xx`

So I probably need a binding redirect for the underlying package Newtonsoft.Json.dll, but where do I put that redirect? Tried `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects=true` but that didn;t solve it.

Comment: What kind of project is that? This is a web application, console? .net core or .net framework? Usually you have to add binding redirects in your web.config/app.config file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.1 that runs as an add-in into Excel. When I run the code outside Excel it does work. It's one of those..

Comment: How about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664372/7225096