# Google Api - System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives'

Tags: c#, .net, dll, google-api, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting the following exception when trying to use the Google Auth API:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The exception happens in Google.Api.Core.dll.

If I check the /Bin folder I can see Sytem.Net.Http.Primitives.dll in there and the version is 4.2.28.0.

I have tried updating the Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries NuGet package but that didn't help.

Is the problem something to do with a mismatch of .dll versions? If so how can I resolve that? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Double check if the assembly file is there in the `bin` folder and if its there, then **try removing the reference and again add it to your project**.

The version should be the same as expected. Also check on your `web.config` too for what it has about this particular assembly.

In your error code, I can see two different versions for the same file. Means probably, you are getting a clash between the existing assembly and the referenced assembly. Check you `web.config` for which version is referenced there and make sure you have the same version added to your project.

This link might help :

[Could not find assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. My app.config has a dependency on System.Net.Http.Primitives, which has newVersion="4.2.28.0". I tried following the steps from the link you posted but to no avail.