# Youtube API V3 Upload video console issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-data-api

I have tried to execute the sample code of Google youtube api V3 which is provided on the link for video upload (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet), I got the attached screenshot error:

[image]

Kindly, guide me on the same.

Comment: I don't think the error has anything to do with the YouTube API..

Comment: @MarkC. hi mark, i appreciate your reply but i have taken the entire project from sample they have provided and started the solution but i was unable to run the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m