# Sign in with google plus ID error "could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0"

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, google-api-dotnet-client, machine.config

I am implementing sign-in with google-plus in my web. But after signing in, this error occurs,

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040) Please try again in several minutes.

I've tried every steps that is mentioned here : [Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives. Located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m)

At last, I've fixed this problem with adding this to machine.config :

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**Problem :** I don't want a *machine.config* changed so I want to move it to *web.config* on a root folder of my web.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to fix this..
deleting **xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"** from  tag fix my problem.. I don't know what's the side effect of that action, can someone tell me??