# Could not load System.Net.Http.Primitives or one of its dependencies...gmail API

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I am aware of the other question on this topic.  Unfortunately, that question did not solve the problem.

My problem is outlined **almost** to the letter in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m). I am running the gmail-api in c# and the authenticator is complaining that it cannot find the System.Net.Http.Primitives file.  I have followed all the steps of the answer--both steps 1 and 2.

Yet, the code still isn't finding the .Primitives version 4.2.29 (the current version of the primitives file).  Is there another step to making sure the code can find the primitives file?  I have updated all of the nuget packages in the solution to the latest versions.  The primitives file is both present in the project and has been redirected to in the App.config file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives. Located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m)

Comment: This is exactly the question that I cited in my question...I followed it to the letter and am still having problems.  That is why I cited it and asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, installing the gmail api into only the .dll where it was called wasn't enough. Instead, I had to install it in all of the projects involved...in this case, the .dll and the unit testing project.  That cleared up the problem.

Still have no idea why.