# Resolution on "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives'" error for .NET DLLs?

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

There are many posts on stackoverflow regarding the System.Net.Http.Primitives assembly error related to the Google .NET API client. The standard workaround involves using App.config/Web.config's bindingRedirect to reroute to the right assembly version at runtime ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m)). As far as I understand, however, this is not an appropriate workaround if application developers must produce DLLs built on the Google .NET APIs (say, as a plugin for another application) because bindingRedirects will only be processed for the plugin's hosting application. There are separate discussions on fudging bindingRedirects for DLLs ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file/1009227#1009227)), but they're loaded with proverbial warnings of "danger: unstable ground. Tread at your own risk". Is there a recommended alternative to bindingRedirects for application developers building DLLs that leverage the Google .NET API?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your issue a little bit more, its not something I have seen before.  Or you could post it here so that we can look into your issue https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues.  I need a way to recreate it if you can reproduces it that would be great.

Comment: Thanks very much, DalmTo. I've tried to clarify the issue in a new Issue Ticket: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/555 . Thanks again!

Comment: I will check it out in the morning thanks for reporting it