# A .net standard lib in a VS extension can't find it's dependency

Tags: c#, .net-standard, vsix

I have a VS extension, targetting .NET 4.6.1. I've refactored some of it into a .NET standard 2.0 dll, referenced by the extension. Where the extension depended on System.Data.SqlClient, the .NET standard dll depends on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, added as a nuget package. The trouble is, at runtime, I get...

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.11.20045.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178092/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-sqlclient), I thought I'd look in the VSIX and sure enough, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll is gloriously missing. I'm not very good with reference issues, but it seems this is totally out of my hands?

I really need this to work, and will happily screen-share or otherwise help anyone who can fix my problem. If you prefer to see the problem in situ, you can clone https://github.com/bbsimonbb/query-first.git then checkout the branch target-core-and-framework.

Comment: Have you setup any binding redirects?

Comment: Binding redirects look a bit difficult and controversial [in a VSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246064/how-to-do-dll-bindingredirect-in-a-vsix-extension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by how [NuGet dependencies are resolved.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) Your extension project "A" references a .NET Standard project "B" that in turn depends on a NuGet package "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient". Therefore, "A" has a **transitive dependency** on "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" through "B". In other words, "A" needs "B", as well as the NuGet package to work.

As I can see from thelinked repository, your extension project uses the old-style format for .NET Framework projects, not the new [SDK-style format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) like your .NET Standard library. When using the old project format, project "A" will only get assemblies of *direct* dependencies like "B" in its output folder, not *indirect* dependencies like the NuGet package. This is why the assemblies are not found. With the new SDK-style project and `PackageReference`, these transitive dependencies are respected. Hence, the package assemblies will be copied to your output folder or extension.

In order to make this work, you need to [migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659684/how-to-upgrade-csproj-files-with-vs2017/42807657#42807657) your .NET Framework project to the new SDK-style format and use `PackageReference` for packages. It seems that this might be tricky for Visual Studio extensions, but it is possible and you can find more on it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917250/is-it-possible-to-write-vs-extensions-using-the-sdk-style-projects). If this is not possible in your case, I guess you will have to resort to use plain old references to the assemblies that you require.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: My project A is a VSIX visual studio extension, so I'm kinda tied to the old style project format. Is there another way of specifying the transitive dependencies ?

Comment: @bbsimonbb The old style does not support transitive dependencies, so I do not think there is another way that is directly supported other than complicated workarounds using e.g. custom build scripts.