# Binding redirect not effective in VSPackage/VSIX

Tags: .net, vsix, vspackage, assembly-binding-redirect, assembly-loading

#### Main Question

I'm using VS2017 (15.9.25) to develop a VSIX VSPackage.

The package uses the `MySqlConnector 1.0.0` NuGet package, which in turn depends on `System.Memory 4.5.4` NuGet package which includes the `System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51` assembly.

When I run my VSPackage in debug mode using the Visual Studio Experimental Instance, my plugin loads, and I can see my custom options pages and the custom commands which I'm adding to the VS context menus. But when I actually *run* the custom command (which tries to retrieve some data using `MySqlConnector`), the database connection fails because the `System.Memory` assembly fails to load.

[image: FileNotFoundException details]

There is some more debugging information provided in the exception message which I don't fully understand:

[image: additional assembly loading details]

My `app.config` contains the following binding redirect:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The `bin/Debug` folder and the generated `.vsix` file both contain `MySqlConnector.dll 1.0.0` and `System.Memory.dll 4.0.1.1`.

Looking at `MySqlConnector.dll` using ReSharper's Assembly Explorer, I see it references `System.Memory 4.0.1.0`, which is the assembly that's failing to load.

My questions are:

1. Why does the `FileNotFoundException` mention 4.0.1.0? Shouldn't the binding redirect cause .NET to try and load 4.0.1.1, which is definitely present?
2. Is there anything special I need to do to configure binding redirects in a VSIX/VSPackage context?
3. What do the extra assembly binding/loading diagnostics (e.g. `=== Pre-bind state information ===` etc) actually mean?
4. What do I need to change to get this assembly to load correctly?

#### More details

I started with the standard VS2017 VSIX package project template, which targets .NET 4.6, and later retargeted my project to .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I thought the issue might be caused by types which are included in .NET Fx 4.7.2 but shipped separately when targeting .NET Fx 4.6, so I tried reinstalling both the `MySqlConnector` and `System.Memory` NuGet packages after changing target to 4.7.2. It made no difference.

I am using traditional `packages.config`-style NuGet configuration.

The VSIX package uses the NuGet package `MySqlConnector 1.0.0` ([project home page](https://mysqlconnector.net/)). The package doesn't list any dependencies explicitly for .NET 4.7.2:

[image: MySqlConnector dependency list from NuGet package manager]

But it appears the dependencies for `.NETFramework,Version=4.7.1` also apply to `4.7.2`, since installing `MySqlConnector` results in the `System.Memory 4.5.4` NuGet package also being installed. This adds a reference to the `System.Memory 4.0.1.1` assembly to my VSIX VSPackage project, with `Copy Local == True`:

[image: System.Memory reference properties]

The checkbox in the project properties for "Auto-generate binding redirects" is checked:
[image: auto-generate binding redirects is checked]

But, oddly, there is no `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` element in the `csproj` file. Perhaps that element doesn't apply to VSIX projects for some reason or it became implicit behaviour at some point?

When I build my project, the `System.Memory.dll` file is being copied from the NuGet packages folder into the binary output folder, as I would expect:

[image: Windows explorer screencap showing System.Memory.dll in output folder]

Inspecting the file in the binary output folder with ILSpy proves that it's the latest version, and matches the assembly binding redirect in `app.config`:

```
// C:\git\[redacted]\bin\Debug\System.Memory.dll
// System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: v4.0.30319
// This assembly is signed with a strong name key.
// Hash algorithm: SHA1
```

Opening the `.vsix` file in the output folder using 7-zip shows that the VSIX also contains `System.Memory.dll`:

[image: VSIX archive contents]

Comment: It might be relevant that my custom button is parented to a context menu which is provided by a _different_ VS extension that I don't own (Beckhoff TwinCAT XAE). I see that mentioned in the `Initial PrivatePath` part of the detailed loading diagnostics but I don't understand the implications of that.

Comment: The TwinCAT PrivatePath turned out to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer is that .NET was trying to load the older version because VSPackage/VSIX projects [do not honor binding redirects configured in `app.config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118966/531971) (which is maintained by NuGet package install/uninstall actions), because they are plugins loaded within the context of Visual Studio's `devenv.exe`, which picks up its primary binding redirect configuration from its own `devenv.exe.config` file that the VSIX can't edit.

Instead, VSIX infrastructure allows for binding redirects to be configured in `.pkgdef` files, which VS pays attention to when loading the VSPackage. The `.pkgdef` file is an output from the VSIX build process, so directly editing it would be rather fragile. The easiest way to maintain .pkgdef binding redirects is to add assembly-scoped instances of the [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ProvideBindingRedirectionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providebindingredirectionattribute) to the VSPackage project's `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. The VSIX build tools will pick up those attributes and generate binding redirects in the `.pkgdef` file when the VSIX is built.

After adding various `ProvideBindingRedirectionAttribute` instances based on the contents of my `app.config`, I can now load the `MySqlConnector` DLL.

Comment: Plus 1, but it's actually named `ProvideBindingRedirectionAttribute`

Comment: @JimWsaysreinstateMonica edited as suggested, thanks