# FileNotFoundException on RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm using `RestSharp` in a portable dll for Xamarin and WP platform. Actually I've created the method `GET` with this code inside of it:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/api/v1/");
var request = new RestRequest(requestUri, Method.GET);
var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
```

I set up a `client` with my base url, in the `request` variable I passed the resource to add to the base url as the documentation says. And finally I execute the request saving the content inside `queryResult`. The problem is that when I execute this code, on this line:

var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/api/");

I get:

> FileNotFoudnException was not Managed
>   System.IO.FileNotFoudnException in RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient.dll
>   Cannot load the file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version = 1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d503a0

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to :

1. Install the [Microsoft Http Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) from NuGet.
2. If already installed, ensure you're on the latest stable version (2.2.29)

Also, check  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370360/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-located-assemblys-m) for more details, as you *may* need to add a dependent assembly to your web.config as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just removed the library and reinstall it again for fix this.