# Including Amazon S3 Nuget with Xamarin Android App Results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, xamarin.android, nuget

When I add the Amazon S3 Nuget package to my xamarin android app, I get the following error,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() ContentUpdater
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Nick.

Update:  Just tried the same with a Windows 10 Universal App and I get this,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll'   WindowsContentUpdater   C:\devoctomy\GitHub\ContentUpdater\WindowsContentUpdater\WindowsContentUpdater.csproj
```

Is the S3 library broken or something?

Comment: From exception, seems like you need Http Client library. Can you try guidance on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19411822/775544

Comment: I already looked at that thread and it didn't help unfortunately.  I think there is something wrong with the amazon sdk as it won't even work with a universal windows 10 app, after adding the references, I get loads of these warnings..

Comment: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 5.2.2 to 5.1.0 
 WindowsContentUpdaterObjectLibrary (>= 1.0.0) -> AWSSDK.S3 (>= 3.3.3) -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (>= 5.2.2) 
 WindowsContentUpdaterObjectLibrary (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (>= 5.1.0)   0"

Comment: For now I've decided to start with a Windows Forms app and a standard .net class library, I will port my code to a portable library when I've got that working.  I'm suspecting the AWS S3 library needs updating perhaps?

Comment: I've found a small library by Kvandike called BasicAWS, that compiles great so may be a solution for now.

Comment: getting the same issue, I'm guessing you didn't have anymore luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late but I managed to fix it.

1. Uninstall all AWSSDK nugets
2. start by adding the Microsoft.Net.Http nuget
3. Add AWSSDK.Core, S3 and then Cognito + whatever else you need

Comment: Thanks, adding the Microsoft.Net.Http nuget directly was sufficient for my problem!